# "Optimaly" reordering the vertices of a hypergraph.

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, hypergraphs

I am not even sure of how to search for an answer to this, or how to approach the problem myself, so I thought I would try to ask it here.

Consider an n-vertex hypergraph where the vertices are numbered from 1 to n. Each edge is given a "score" based on the lowest numbered vertex it contains.

Is it possible to efficiently renumber the vertices in a way that maximizes the sum of all the edge scores?

I'm not really seeing any way to do this short of the naive method of trying every permutation. I'd appreciate a shove in the right direction.